# Cant start gui aplication created with Qt4 and Python 3.4 and Unable to find QStringList class

Tags: python-3.x, qt4, pyqt4

I create GUI Design in Qt4 and you can see the Design [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3ADc.png).

Than, with pyuic4 i converted design into `GuiVezba2DialogQt4.py`.
Here you can see a Code for that class:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(554, 407)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 411, 61))
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
    self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
    self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2 = QtGui.QWidget(Dialog)
    self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 411, 41))
             self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget_2"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
    self.label_20 = QtGui.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.label_20.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_20"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_20)
    self.label_21 = QtGui.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.label_21.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_21"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_21)
    self.label_22 = QtGui.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.label_22.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_22"))
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_22)
    self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
    self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 291, 171))
    self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 91, 21))
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 51, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
    self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
    self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 70, 111, 16))
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 110, 111, 16))
    self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 111, 16))
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 90, 111, 16))
    self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 131, 16))
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.label_12 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 131, 16))
    self.label_12.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_12"))
    self.label_13 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 131, 16))
    self.label_13.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_13"))
    self.label_14 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 131, 16))
    self.label_14.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_14"))
    self.label_15 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
    self.label_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 130, 131, 16))
    self.label_15.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_15"))
    self.groupBox_2 = QtGui.QGroupBox(Dialog)
    self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 130, 241, 171))
    self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox_2"))
    self.label_10 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 71, 16))
    self.label_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_10"))
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.groupBox_2)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 30, 71, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lineEdit_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
    self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 60, 61, 16))
    self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
    self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 80, 71, 16))
    self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
    self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 100, 71, 16))
    self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
    self.label_11 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 120, 71, 16))
    self.label_11.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_11"))
    self.pushButton_5 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
    self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_5"))
    self.label_19 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_19.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 80, 121, 16))
    self.label_19.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_19"))
    self.label_18 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_18.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 60, 131, 16))
    self.label_18.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_18"))
    self.label_17 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_17.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 131, 16))
    self.label_17.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_17"))
    self.label_16 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox_2)
    self.label_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 120, 131, 16))
    self.label_16.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_16"))

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button1", None))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button2", None))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button3", None))
    self.label_20.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Konektuj se na bazu", None))
    self.label_21.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ucitaj Detaljne Tacke", None))
    self.label_22.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ucitaj Parcele", None))
    self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "GroupBox1", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Oznaka Parcele:", None))
    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button4", None))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label4", None))
    self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label9", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label3", None))
    self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label5", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Povrsina parcele je:", None))
    self.label_12.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Broj Prelomnih Tacaka je:", None))
    self.label_13.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Nacin koriscenja je:", None))
    self.label_14.setText(_translate("Dialog", "WKT format geometrije je:", None))
    self.label_15.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ucitaj podatke:", None))
    self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "GroupBox2", None))
    self.label_10.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Broj Tacke", None))
    self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label6", None))
    self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label7", None))
    self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label8", None))
    self.label_11.setText(_translate("Dialog", "label11", None))
    self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Button5", None))
    self.label_19.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Koordinata Y je:", None))
    self.label_18.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Koordinata X je:", None))
    self.label_17.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Da li ucestvuje u parceli:", None))
    self.label_16.setText(_translate("Dialog", "WKT oblik Geometrije", None))
```

Than in my main python file - `Vezba2.py` I have this:

```
import pypyodbc
import DetaljnaTacka
import Poligon
import Parcela
from GuiVezba2DialogQt4 import *
import sys

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
       QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton_4, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.
dispmessage)

    def dispmessage(self):
        self.ui.label_10.setText("Hello ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i Run program, with debagger i put Break point at `myapp=MyForm()`. When that step try to execute, program is over. I don't see created GUI and i dont see any error.

What should i do please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made i mistake. I typed:
           `app = QtGui.QGuiApplication` instead `app = QtGui.QApplication`

Comment: Only part of this is an answer to the question. You should leave the first line of your answer and mark it as the answer to your question. Then move the rest of this post to a new question. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.